# c++ : convert std::map<std::string, double> to std::map<std::string_view, double>

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have a private `std::map` inside my class `std::map<std::string, double>`. How can I transform is to `std::map<std::string_view, double>` to return to the user? I'd like to have the following prototype here

```
const std::map<std::string_view, double>&
MyClass::GetInternalMap() const;
```

Comment: What's the motivation?  Returning a `const&` is already effectively a "view".  None of the underlying memory will be copied.

Comment: @0x5453 For the moment I’m doing a clean-up for my code to optimize the performance, and that was a question for me how to do it in a better way. This exact example is just an illustration for my intention

Comment: There's a big difference: string is owning and string_view not. So they're not the same.

Answer (score 5):

You should not return the new `map` by const reference.  You would be returning a dangling reference to a temp `map` that was destroyed when `GetInternalMap()` exits.  If you want to return a const reference, then you should return the source `map` as-is, eg:

```cpp
const std::map<std::string, double>& MyClass::GetInternalMap() const
{
    return myvalues;
}
```

Otherwise, return the new `map` by value instead:

```cpp
std::map<std::string_view, double> MyClass::GetInternalMap() const;
```

That being said, a `std::map<std::string,double>` is not directly convertible to a `std::map<std::string_view,double>`, so you would have to manually iterate the source `map` one element at a time, assigning each one to the target `map`, eg:

```cpp
std::map<std::string_view, double> MyClass::GetInternalMap() const
{
    std::map<std::string_view, double> result;
    for(auto &p : myvalues) {
        result[p.first] = p.second;
        // or: result.emplace(p.first, p.second);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Fortunately, a `std::pair<std::string,double>` is implicitly convertible to a `std::pair<std::string_view,double>`, so you could simply use the `map` constructor that takes an iterator range as input, and let `map` assign the elements for you, eg:

```cpp
std::map<std::string_view, double> MyClass::GetInternalMap() const
{
    return {myvalues.begin(), myvalues.end()};
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for a quick answer ! I was looking for any kind of stl solution here but nevertheless your approach is fine for me also

Comment: I think you can construct the `result` map directly using the two-iterator constructor. I tested GCC, Clang, and MSVC; they all accepted `return { begin(myvalues), end(myvalues) };` as the entire function body.